# BetterProgramming Practice: more functions vs multi-use functions

Tags: javascript

Which is more efficient and Why? (will include an example)

Writing multiple functions for each specific task or one function with very similar purposes but only does executes one of the needs at a time.

For example: JavaScript, writing to a google docs spreadsheet

Making a function insert or delete depending on the parameters set

```
function insertOrDelete(insert, delete){
//if insert != null insert row
//if delete !=null delete row
//only one of the tasks are meant to be done at a time
}
```

vs
two separate functions for each task, this is a poor example as they aren't the most similar but my point I'm trying to get across is if it is more efficient for less coding blocks and reusing the same block as much as possible or to have it point directly to the block the running very specific tasks? WHY?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain experienced programmers will agree with me that it's better to have this functions **separated**.

Somebody once said:

> Functions should do one thing, one thing only, and **do it well**.

So, yeah, you have the answer right there.

Separating the functions makes the code easier to **read**, **maintainable** and **testable**.

Just imagine what reading these two function on a sleepless night calls would look like:

```
insertOrDelete(null, 1);
```

vs

```
Delete(1);
```

The second choice is more obvious, less magic and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to write "Cohesive" code:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)

This basically means that classes and methods should do only one thing and do it well. So to answer your question directly two separate functions are better this is as it allows you to more easily reuse your code.

If you really want the insert or delete functionality as you have described then do this

```
function insertOrDelete(insertVar, deleteVar){
    if insert != null insert(insertVar)
    if delete !=null delete(deleteVar)
}

function insert(insertVar){
    insert(insertedVar);
}

function insert(deleteVar){
    delete(deleteVar);
}
```

Personally I think that using the null reference is a bit hacky so would probaly do something more like this

```
function insertOrDelete(var, insertOrDelete){
    if(insertOrDelete == "insert"){
        // insert it
    }else if(insertOrDelete == "delete"){
        // delete it
    }else{
        // error
    }
}
```

Comment: To take your answer to the extreme - it's still preferred to have multiple functions over one big one, even if you have say 100 more functions to run? Couldn't that get confusing, jumping between functions? (I'm new to more robust programming, so maybe it's not as confusing as *not* separating the functions can be).

Comment: If your functions a well named and they are truly cohesive it often means you can almost treat them as a black box. You should try to use functions as a means of abstraction in your code. The main benefit as I see if is you can reuse your functions. This means you write less code which in my opinion almost always makes it less confusing. Imagine using a function like the one you suggested with 100 variables make sure it was the right one that wasn't a null value would be a nightmare

Comment: Sorry just realized you weren't the one who wrote the question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is going to get you down-votes - because it can be opinion based. You could run a test on a group of functions or modular blocks of combined functions - and sometimes you would get an unexpected result one being "faster" - in certain circumstances - and not in others... how many times does it run... etc.

However, the differences in most cases are so small - that modularity / reusability / readability is chosen over any micro speed you might get out of obsessing over this.

If you have a function where you double something, it would make sense to make that stand alone.

```
function double(input) {
    return (input * 2);
}
```

Then if you have another function... you could use that doubling within - instead of writing it again...

*OR NOT!
It's all based on the scenario!*

BUT Experience will lead you to choose a path - and I'm willing to bet that modularity will show you the light.

Comment: I think that the "opinion based" mods are far too aggressive.  There are lots of legitimate questions where the answer may be partially opinion-based, but there are objective advantages and disadvantages to doing things a different way.

Comment: I can agree sometimes about that / but I wanted to warn - so they didn't get pummeled.

Comment: I agree with @DanielAllenLangdon - this could be opinion based, but it sounds like he's asking more about best practices (which, in a way, are also opinion).  Say something runs in .02 seconds, and writing it another way takes 3 seconds...but the .02 second one is incredibly convoluted - what should we prefer then? The convoluted function, or a clearly written function that takes more time?  Surely there are some objective standards that can be applied to get an "answer"?

Comment: The question wasn't that clear. Also, the word "Best" is clearly subjective - unless you can clearly show the differences with clarity and a solid conclusion. There are situations when a very specific small - super ugly - function could be used - and run much faster than a huge machine of modules. So, what is less efficient in one place would be different in another. For the record - I didn't vote anything down. I'm just trying to actually answer the question the way I believe it should be answered. I addressed your entire comment in my answer to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, it is best for each function to do one thing.

There are, of course, exceptions.  For example, if you have a function that handles a request from an external source, it might need to do many different things, in which case you could create a different function for each operation and call them as appropriate.

It may sound simple in the `insertOrDelete` example you've given, but I've seen functions that were thousands of lines long with huge collections of case statements.  That's not where you want to go.

One function should do one thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely opinion-based.

There are times where it slows you down to split every single function into separate functions. Sometimes time is more important than future usability and maintenance.

I find myself writing everything out and splitting things out as separate functions when I find myself needing something similar later in the application.

I don't see a point in taking the time writing everything in separate functions, just to have 100 individual functions and 80 of them are used one time in your whole application. There are appropriate times to do it both ways.